# When does venv need activation?

Tags: python, python-venv

When using Pycharm, I make my virtual environment when I m creating a new project and then never have to think about activating it or anything. It works just fine.

When I m using the terminal on my Mac OS, I need to create the virtual environment and then also activate it.

I also have to activate it for VS Code.

How do I know when I need to activate my virtual environment? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, you can just create the virtual environment once for each project and then just activate it every time you work on the terminal. You know that it is activated when it shows `(your-env-name-here)` as prefix.

Comment: You always need to activate virtual environment if you want that command "python" corresponds to the python executable of the virtual environment. PyCharm just has been doing the activation for you. Like paaksing said, you know that virtual environment is activated when there is a corresponding prefix in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To activate a virtual environment from the terminal, you need to source a file that the `venv` module created. This file typically will be in the `bin` directory of your project (`ej. my_project/folder/bin)` and will be named `activate`.

So to activate the environment in your shell you would run the command

`source my_project/folder/bin/activate`

You should know if you're already **IN** the virtual environment, when you see the project's name parsed to some part of your shell prompt. If you're already into your virtual environment, you can leave it with the `deactivate` command.

[image: shell prompt]